# Apache POI zip download failed to verify using gpg?

Tags: apache-poi

Just tried to verify the Apache POI zip download using gpg and the KEYS file.
poi-bin-3.15-20160924.zip

I got a BAD signature error.
gpg --verify poi-src-3.15-20160924.zip.asc poi-bin-3.15-20160924.zip
gpg: Signature made 09/18/16 04:47:42 New Zealand Standard Time
gpg:                using RSA key 527EB833FA3ADDC2
gpg: BAD signature from "David North " [unknown]

Any suggestions?
I tried the download from both US and Europe mirrors.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing the "src" hash with the "bin" archive.

Should be

```
gpg --verify poi-**bin**-3.15-20160924.zip.asc poi-bin-3.15-20160924.zip
```

Comment: Thanks! (Note to self, always check the obvious.)